# dynamic button onclick event inside for loop

Tags: android

i'm using this code to create dynamic buttons within for loop..

```
LinearLayout linearLayout =  (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
for (int i=0 ; i<10; i++){
LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

TextView textview = new TextView(this);
textview.setText("Text view" + i);
textview.setId(i);

l.addView(textview);
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText("View");
button.setId(i);
button.setWidth(90);
button.setHeight(60);
l.addView(button);
linearLayout.addView(l);//if you want you can layout params linearlayout
}
```

now i want to add onclick event to each button based on the iterating i value.. can any one suggest me how to implement this... thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create an arraay of buttons...

```
Button[] buttons=new Button[10];
```

and instead of this line

```
Button button = new Button(this);
```

in your for loop..use

```
 button[i] = new Button(this);
```

and in the same loop set your onclicklistener like this..and based on the question you were asking **add onclick event to each button based on the iterating i value** i think you have same onclicklistener for all buttons..

```
    button[i].setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
        //your onclicklistener code
}
```

});

Answer (score 2):

Create a `List` of `Button`'s then add each `Button` to that list after its created...

```
List<Button> list = new ArrayList<Button>();
for (int i=0 ; i<10; i++){
LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

TextView textview = new TextView(this);
textview.setText("Text view" + i);
textview.setId(i);

l.addView(textview);
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText("View");
button.setId(i);
button.setWidth(90);
button.setHeight(60);
l.addView(button);
linearLayout.addView(l);//if you want you can layout params linearlayout
list.add(button);
}
```

Then use advanced for loop to iterate through the list and add click listener for each Button..

```
for(Button btn : list){
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Outside your loop create a new `View.OnClickListener`:

```
OnClickListener ocl = new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){
        case 1:
            // click action
            break;
        case 2: 
            // click action
            break;
        }
        // ...etc
    }
}
```

Based on the ID of your button, in this case the iteration of `i`, you can perform various actions.  This can be anything, however, like an `if...else` block on the text of the button or a tag you set.

Then inside your loop, before you `addView(l)`, assign it:

```
button.setOnClickListener(ocl);
```

Answer (score 0):

add button.setOnClickListener(this); in the forloop

and add these code below oncreate():::

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
switch(v.getId()){
case 0:
// click action for first btn
break;
case 1: 
// click action for 2nd btn
break;
soon upto 
case 9: 
// click action for 9th btn
break;
}
}
```

also ypur activity must implement onClickListerner.