# Creating an array of buttons using "for loop" and using the value inside to change a bool-array value

Tags: java, arrays

(**Updated**) Sorry if this is getting more and more like a guide. Is there any other site I should post this on?

I'm making a yatzy game and I'm on my way learning for loops. My method is similar to the top answer's in this question: 
[dynamic button onclick event inside for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146028/dynamic-button-onclick-event-inside-for-loop)
Here's my code: (Yes I'm mixing languages, I'm sorry)

```
package se.balderskolan.yatzy;

    import java.util.Random;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btKasta;
Random r = new Random();
int[] tarningar = new int[5];
int[] bilder = new int [6];
ImageButton [] img= new ImageButton[5];
boolean [] bool = new boolean[5];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btKasta = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btKasta);

    bilder [0]=R.drawable.b1; //Pictures of the dices
    bilder [1]=R.drawable.b2;
    bilder [2]=R.drawable.b3;
    bilder [3]=R.drawable.b4;
    bilder [4]=R.drawable.b5;
    bilder [5]=R.drawable.b6;

    img [0] = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbt1); //The grafical dices
    img [1] = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbt2);
    img [2] = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbt3);
    img [3] = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbt4);
    img [4] = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbt5);


    //The die-buttons (save or not)
    img [0].setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(bool [0] == false) {
                        bool [0] = true;
                    }

                    else{
                        bool [0] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            );

    img [1].setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(bool [1] == false) {
                        bool [1] = true;
                    }

                    else{
                        bool [1] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            );

    img [2].setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(bool [2] == false) {
                        bool [2] = true;
                    }

                    else{
                        bool [2] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            );

    img [3].setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(bool [3] == false) {
                        bool [3] = true;
                    }

                    else{
                        bool [3] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            );

    img [4].setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(bool [4] == false) {
                        bool [4] = true;
                    }

                    else{
                        bool [4] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            );

    /*I want to replace the code above with something like this below

    for(imgbt=0; imgbt<5; imgbt++){
        img [imgbt].setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if(bool [imgbt] == false) {
                            bool [imgbt] = true;
                        }
                        else{
                            bool [imgbt] = false;
                        }

                    }
                }
        );

    }
    */

  //The die-throwing button
    btKasta.setOnClickListener(             
        new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                        tarningar [i]=r.nextInt(6);

                        if (bool[i]==false){
                            img [i].setImageResource(bilder [tarningar[i]]);}
                        else{}
                    }                   
                }
            }
    );
}

    }
```

(I can add that I have succesfully had the bottons save dices using the code without the for-loop.)

After doing some research in my code I discovered the following about the button-for-loop:

- The value of "imgbt" is 5 at row

  ```
  if(bool [imgbt] == false)
  ```

  Which gives me the "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"-error.
- All of the buttons always changes the bool-value of bool [5] (Which doesn't exist. I found this by increasing the nuber of arrays created up in the declaration)

If I declare

```
    int imgbt = 0
```

inside the for-loop eclipse gives me the error:

```
    Cannot refer to a non-final variable imgbt inside an inner class defined in a different method
```

(Can someone explain this error?)

So do you know any solution to my problem, or another way to work around it, please do not hesitate to awnser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your real problem was that you were using a mutable, non-final, variable when defining an override in a class. So if you modify the code to look like the fallowing:

```
for(imgbt=0; imgbt<5; imgbt++){
    public final someInteger = imgbt;
    img [imgbt].setOnClickListener(
           new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(bool [someInteger] == false) {
                        bool [someInteger] = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        bool [someInteger] = false;
                    }
              }
         }
    );
}
```

It should work out just fine.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really have much to do with Android, it's basic Java. In short:

- arrays start from index 0
- an object array (such as `Boolean`) is by default initialized with `null`s
- you need to make the two arrays the same size

So,

- start your loop from 0
- use `booolean[]` instead of `Boolean[]` or initialize it with `Boolean.FALSE` before use`
- make both arrays size 6

Comment: Thanks for your help! I learned a bit from it. Despite that my problem is not yet fixed.

Comment: This is getting tutorial-like, so SO might not be the best place. Spend some more time with your Java book and learn how to use the debugger to see where the problem is. And maybe show all of your code, so people don't have to guess. BTW, the canonical way to write a `for` loop for arrays is: `for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { array[i] = foo;}`

Comment: I'm not sure I understood how you ment I should write a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the array, like this:

```
Boolean bool[] = new Boolean[]{false, false, false, false, false, false, false};
```